# Remote Desktop freezes while connecting from Windows

Tags: networking, gnome, windows, remote-desktop

I am currently working on a Windows PC, from which I connect to a Ubuntu PC through Ubuntu's native remote desktop. But it is very unstable since the screen freezes all the time and even disconnects. I won't be able to connect again after a while.

Is there a solution for this, or perhaps some alternative to the remote desktop that Ubuntu offers?

[image: ubuntu remote desktop]